# Schwarz theorem in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Is there a version of the Schwarz theorem $ \partial_x \partial_y = \partial_y \partial_x $ in the theory of complex functions of several variables and complex analysis ? It would be nice that you show me where I can find it on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the real case:

If $z = x+iy$ then $\partial_z = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x - i\partial_y)$.

Suppose we have another complex variable $w = s+it$. Then $\partial_w = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_s-i\partial_t)$.

So $\partial_z \partial_w = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x - i\partial_y)\frac{1}{2}(\partial_s-i\partial_t) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_s-i\partial_t)\frac{1}{2}(\partial_x - i\partial_y) = \partial_w \partial_z$.